# can we run airflow templates without using cloud composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

**I have an airflow template which is written using python code. Currently, I am running it on cloud composer by uploading to dags file.. is there any possibility that I can run airflow template without using cloud composer**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want to run a DAG locally? There are a few ways you can do this:

1) Download airflow on your own and run it on your machine:
`pip install apache-airflow`

2) Use a dockerized version of airflow to ensure your dependencies are the same. There are a few options to try:

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

https://github.com/astronomer/astro-cli